# ajax image not showing on form submit except in Firefox where it shows fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

Here is the code am using to show an ajax image on form submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#form_id').bind('submit', function() {
      $('#img-div').show();
    });
    $('#form_id').submit('submit', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
..........................
......................
    });

});
```

This works fine in one page, and doesn't in a different page.
Where as on Firefox both pages work fine.

What could be wrong in the above code...

**EDIT:**

This only happens in one particular case. The AJAX call makes the page unresponsive and the image does not show, if I show a loading image, it stops animating for the duration of ajax call., I tried using jQuery UI dialog, still same result, works fine on Firefox though...

Answer (score 2):

OK. `.bind('submit',function(){})` is analogous to `.submit(function(){})`. And the `.submit()` function doesn't need 'submit' as an argument.

I think the code you want is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form_id').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#img-div').show()
        //......................
        //......................
    })
})
```

Try that and let me know. I suspect Firefox may have been more tolerant to your broken code, whereas other browsers just broke when it hit it.

Comment: Same problem, Firefox shows fine but all other browsers don't show the loading image on submit. When I put alerts before and after the "$('#img-div').show()", the animated image shows until second alert, after that it stops animating...

Comment: I suspect you'll need to pre-load the image to get it working reliably. To test this out, just pop the same image somewhere else on the page and see if it makes a difference. If so, we can help with preloading (or Google can)

Comment: I tried that, and the image loads just fine, but the image stops animating whenever the AJAX call is executed via $.getJSON, or $.get, and when I try to show the image upon button click, and hide it after the AJAX call, it won't even show.